# r ggplot colored histogram is wrong colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have stripped down my code to the following MWE:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

x<-rnorm(1000)

df <- data.frame(x = x)
df <- mutate(df, colors = 'blue')

p1<-ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill=colors)) +
  geom_histogram()
p1

p2<-ggplot(df, aes(x=x), fill=colors) +
  geom_histogram()
p2

p3<-ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_histogram(fill=colors)
p3
```

I want my histogram to be blue, but `p1` is red, `p2` is grey and `p3` throws an error.

In my actual application I will use more than one colour, hence the use of `mutate`, I assume it I can get it to work for one, it will work for the others too.

Perhaps my MWE above was too MWE. Here is a more elaborate code:

```
x<-rnorm(1000)

df <- data.frame(x = x)
df <- mutate(df, colors = case_when(
    x < quantile(x,0.25) ~ "red",
    x >= quantile(x,0.25) & x < quantile(x,0.5) ~ "orange",
    x >= quantile(x,0.5) & x < quantile(x,0.75) ~ "blue",
    x >= quantile(x,0.75) ~ "green"
    )
  )

p1<-ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill=colors)) +
  geom_histogram()
p1
```

This returns a histogram with four colours, but they are not blue, green orange and red!

Comment: why are you using two fill arguments in your third ggplot() call?
If I'm correct you just want your three histograms to be different colours? You don't need to define colour as a variable in the data.frame()

Comment: @AsifLalDin Oops, that was a sloppy copy-paste by me. I don't want three histograms, these are the three attempts I made to solve the problem.

Comment: you can see the two answers below, that should sort it. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
x<-rnorm(1000)

df <- data.frame(x = x)

p1<-ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data=df, aes(x=x),fill="blue")
p1
```

The `fill` argument can't understand the value of one column.

If you have different colors, this will do:

```
p4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill=colors)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","green","orange","red"))
p4
```

Please note the colors in alphabetical order.

[image]

Comment: This is true, but I need the fill bit to be dependent on the colour stated in the df.

Comment: To be precise, using mutate allows me to have the histogram multicolored. That works, but seems to go only to default colours. Hence my question.

Comment: ggplot() + geom_histogram(data=df, aes(x=x),fill=unique(df$colors))

Comment: @Geoff isn't it a static approach and you need to define the colors again as values. Please check my approach, you may find it useful.

Answer (score 4):

If the desired values are already contained in the dataframe, use `scale_*_identity()`.  By default, there is no guide produced so you need to use the `guide` argument so that one is generated if needed.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, fill = colors)) +
  geom_histogram(color = "white") +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
p4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill=colors)) +
  geom_histogram(col="white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=df$colors)
p4
```

If you specify the colour directly in your data frame, then use the `scale_fill_manual` function and specify the colour manually. In this case, you only have one value (a constant).

It's easier to see with more than one colour.

```
df <- mutate(df, colors = sample(c('blue','red'), replace=TRUE, size=1000))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill=colors)) +
      geom_histogram(col="white") +
      scale_fill_manual(values=df$colors)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Main Idea:** Convert the color field as factor and use the levels to get the diff colors in the scale_fill_manual function. Hope it helps, if I understand your Q correctly!!!

```
x<-rnorm(1000)
col <- if_else(between(x,-1,1), "red", "blue")

#color <- c("blue", "red")
df <- data.frame(x = x, color = as.factor(col))

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill = color)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = levels(df$color))
plot(p1)
```

You will get the desired result as below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
library(ggplot2)

x<-rnorm(1000)

df <- data.frame(x = x)

p1<-ggplot(df, aes(x=x, )) +
  geom_histogram(fill='blue',col='white')
p1

p2<-ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_histogram(fill='red',col='white')
p2

p3<-ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_histogram(fill='green',col='white')
p3
```

This is a simple of doing it.